# Outer Join Excluding Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the following query I have rows excluded from the results even though I know they should be there.  I narrowed it down to the 5th join:
                LEFT OUTER JOIN BDNDETL W ON
                    W.CODE = B.WP
If I remove that join and the columns that are referred to by alias "W", I get all of the rows that I expect. There are rows in W that don't have a match in B based on W.CODE = B.WP, but I thought the LEFT OUTER condition would catch these but it doesn't. It seems to just treat it like an INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT
    p.p2 AS "Section",
    d.d9 AS "Alt WBS",
    p.p3 AS "Year",
    B.ca1 AS "WBS",
    concat(b.ca1,'/',b.ca2,'/',b.wp,b.descrip) AS "Work Package",
    B.WP,
    w.d9 AS "Cost Category",
    B.C3 AS "Provider",
    b.c1 AS "TType",
    w.d4 AS "WP GLA Cat",
    U.COSTSET,
    CONVERT(varchar, T.PD_FINISH, 101) period,
    SUM(A.ALLOWANCE1 + A.ALLOWANCE2 + A.ALLOWANCE3 + A.ALLOWANCE4 + A.ALLOWANCE5 + A.BASIC + A.BONUS + A.COMMODITY + A.DIRECT + A.ENHANCED + A.NIERS + A.OVERTIME + A.PENSION + A.PILON + A.REDUNDANCY) Value
FROM
    TPHASE A JOIN CAWP B ON
         B.PROGRAM = A.PROGRAM AND B.CAWPID = A.CAWPID
            JOIN MULTPROG X ON
                A.PROGRAM = X.SUBPROGRAM
            JOIN PROGRAM P ON
                A.PROGRAM = P.PROGRAM
            JOIN BDNDETL D ON
                D.CODE = B.CA1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN BDNDETL W ON
                W.CODE = B.WP
            JOIN COSTDETL U ON
                A.CLASS = U.CLASS
            JOIN RCUTOFF T ON
                A.DF_DATE BETWEEN T.PD_START AND T.PD_FINISH
WHERE
    X.MASTER = @master AND
    D.BREAKFILE = @wbsfile AND
    U.INSTANCE = @costdetlid AND
    T.INSTANCE = @cutoffid AND
    W.BREAKFILE = @wpbdn
GROUP BY
    p.p2,
    d.d9,
    p.p3,
    B.ca1,
    concat(b.ca1,'/',b.ca2,'/',b.wp,b.descrip),
    B.WP,
    w.d9,
    B.C3,
    b.c1,
    w.d4,
    U.COSTSET,
    T.PD_FINISH
;
```

Comment: the problem is with the where condition W.BREAKFILE = @wpbdn; include this in the on condition of the left join [ LEFT OUTER JOIN BDNDETL W ON
                W.CODE = B.WP AND  W.BREAKFILE = @wpbdn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
    W.BREAKFILE = @wpbdn
```

fails when there is no match.  Why?  Because `W.BREAKFILE` is `NULL`.  You should move it to the appropriate `ON` clause:

```
       LEFT OUTER JOIN BDNDETL W ON
            W.CODE = B.WP AND W.BREAKFILE = @wpbdn
```

And, a piece of advice.  When you are mixing `inner` and `left` joins, I strongly recommend that you put all the inner joins first followed by the `left join`s:

```
FROM TPHASE A JOIN
     CAWP B
     ON B.PROGRAM = A.PROGRAM AND B.CAWPID = A.CAWPID JOIN
     MULTPROG X
     ON A.PROGRAM = X.SUBPROGRAM JOIN
     PROGRAM P
     ON A.PROGRAM = P.PROGRAM JOIN
     BDNDETL D
     ON D.CODE = B.CA1 JOIN
     COSTDETL U
     ON A.CLASS = U.CLASS JOIN
     RCUTOFF T
     ON A.DF_DATE BETWEEN T.PD_START AND T.PD_FINISH LEFT JOIN
     BDNDETL W
     ON W.CODE = B.WP
```

This makes the logic much easier to follow.  The idea is that the inner joins do the filtering, then the left join says "keep all those rows and add these additional columns if they match".

Answer (score 3):

you have `W.BREAKFILE = @wpbdn` in your where clause, the null value of left join can't pass this filter.